# Geography point and integer in multicolumn PostgreSQL index

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I want to create a multicolumn spatial index on a geography point and integer in order to do efficient spatial queries. The integer is a user_id and queries are always limited to a single user. Is a multicolumn gin index the best approach?

Comment: I wouldn't think gin would work very well for something that is two-dimensional, even though it is a point, a gist (R-tree) index still uses a 2D bounding box for lookup. One option might be use a geohash of the point and concatenate the userID in some way, at which point you can use a good old b-tree, or create a multi-column b-tree index on userID and geohash. Databases that don't support R-trees, use geohashes for fast spatial lookups, so I have seen similar techniques in MongoDB, for example, but have never tried in Postgres.

Comment: Make an expression index on 3D points, with user ID as Z?

Comment: These are good suggestions but I was hoping to do it in a way that was more transparent